# How should I display header and footer on other than 'Home' page?

Tags: javascript, html, header, footer

Should I do traditional copy paste the header and footer on every page, or is there any way that I can display it using JavaScript on every page!

Just expecting that if I would save some kilobytes on my .html files by rendering my header and footer on each page via JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it will make life lot simpler, but in response to your query, utilise javascript as follows.

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script type=module src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <my-header></my-header> 
      
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      
      <my-footer></my-footer>
    </body>
     
    </html>
```

**about.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script type=module src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <my-header></my-header> 
      
      <h1>About Page</h1>
      
      <my-footer></my-footer>
    </body>
     
    </html>
```

**contact.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script type=module src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <my-header></my-header> 
      
      <h1>Contact Page</h1>
      
      <my-footer></my-footer>
    </body>
     
    </html>
```

**index.js**

```
    class MyHeader extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
        <header>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href=index.html>Home</a></li>
              <li><a href=about.html>About</a></li>
              <li><a href=contact.html>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>`;
      }
    }
    customElements.define("my-header", MyHeader);
    
    class MyFooter extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
        <footer>
          &copy; 2022 My Company
        </footer>`;
      }
    }
    customElements.define("my-footer", MyFooter);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I mean it is a good practice to use JS for rendering headers and footers on my pages, Thank You

Comment: Yes, that is entirely dependent on the number of web-pages on your website, but I believe it is beneficial to investigate each case while learning.
JavaScript is used to build user interaction into web-pages etc, in addition to using effective code, by not repeating yourself.
Don't Repeat Yourself is a principle used by computer programmers to create more effective code (DRY).

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend using a frontend framework, such as Angular, Vue, Svelte, etc. You can create components for your headers and footers and then reused these across multiple places.

Comment: For a minimal framework, consider [petite vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue).